# OSError: [WinError 10057] Запрос на отправку или получение данных (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Tags: python, сокет

При написании сервера на Python возникает ошибка с подключением.

Вот код:

> Server

```
import socket
import json
file = open("configs.json", "r").read()
configs = json.loads(file)
name = configs["server-name"]
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("127.0.0.1",int(configs["port"])))
server.listen(5)

while True:
    client, address = server.accept()
    data = server.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    client.send("Welcome to {0}!".format(name))
    print(data)
```

> Client

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 25565))

while True:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    print(data)
```

В конфиге указан правильный адрес и порт. При старте клиента в сервере возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyWebServer\Server.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = server.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
OSError: [WinError 10057] Запрос на отправку или получение данных  (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что нужно использовать `client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")` вместо `server.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")`. Данные получаются от подключившегося клиента, а не от серверного сокета.